# Pyomo - how to initialize an expression for t=0 within a constraint function

Tags: if-statement, optimization, constraints, pyomo

While creating constraint for time-indexed model, is there a way to initialize a constraint expression for t=0 instead of using if-else?

My current code: def soc_constraint(model, t): if t==1: return model.soc[t] == model.initialSoC - ...  else: return model.soc[t] == model.soc[t-1] - ...

Hoping to check if I can optimize this further by avoiding an if-else check. The first index t here is defined as 1, but it can be adjusted to 0 if it helps in optimizing.

Comment: from the info you provided, what you have is fine.  You need to do an if-else check if you are constructing a family of constraints and you want the first one treated (constructed) differently.  Print your model and make sure it looks like you want it with `model.pprint()`.  If it isn't, post more information in your question, and format your code as code using the editing tools for clarity.